# Save a file in pdf or xls format using java and itext

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am creating a pdf file using itext but i want to open a dialog box to prompt the user to enter the name and location of the file before saving.I have tried JFileChooser but its not working in server client architecture.Kindly suggest a component which can be used.I will be thankful for any help!!!

Am using JSF and Primefaces(Filedownload also not working.)

Comment: Please post your code here. Without observing the code it is difficult to give any solution.

Comment: Am using the following code....
File file=new File(rpttype+"ReportGeneratedon"+datenow+"at"+timenow+".pdf");
  JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
  fileChooser.setSelectedFile(file);
  int retval = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(fileChooser);
  if (retval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {   
    file= fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    System.out.println(file);
   }

Comment: PrimeFaces filedownload should be the way to go. I suggest you to open a new question with your `p:fileDownload` related problem.